# Why does SSIS on Prem require its own Azure SSIS IR (Proxy)?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have a linked service from Azure data factory to onprem SQL server.
The linked service is using a Self-Hosted IR.
Why on earth do I need an Azure-SSIS Proxy to connect to the SSIS? What am I gaining??
Why can't it use the Self-Hosted IR?

The communication is working, but I just need to understand why.

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data movement uses Data Factory copy activity, it does not need Azure SSIS integration runtime.
If data movement logic is inside SSIS package, and uses Execute SSIS package activity, it needs Azure SSIS integration runtime, and self-hosted IR as proxy.